# проблема с подключением intellij idea к mysql (работа с MaxCompute)

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

[image: код]

Ошибка: script must bind a maxcompute project to compile, please bind a maxCompute project in a script editor toolbar

Перевод: скрипт должен связать проект maxcompute для компиляции, пожалуйста, свяжите проект maxCompute на панели инструментов редактора скриптов

Допустим, я могу создать отдельно MaxCompute Studio(Или MaxCompute Java - что из этого нужно? ), а как дальше из связать этот файл с моим JDBC Project. И вообще, может MaxCompute какая-то ошибка, мне ведь по факту нужно иметь в БД 140 слов и вытаскивать из для своей будущей проги, а

MaxCompute Studio - это инструмент интегрированной среды разработки больших данных (IDE), предоставляемый платформой MaxCompute и устанавливаемый на клиенте разработчика.

В общем, не понимаю зачем он мне нужен, но если все-таки нужен, помогите как исправить ошибку.
Впервые работаю с БД.

Comment: О боже, это что за версия intellij idea? Или это тема такая?

Comment: обычная тёмная тема Darcula

Comment: Не понятна ваша цель. Что вы хотите? Подключится к бд через intellij idea, jdbc api или какой-то MaxCompute?

Comment: работала с плагином database navigator, так как у меня комьюнити версия, по видео урокам пыталась подключиться через jdbc и вот такая ошибка непонятная вылезла

Comment: Не смотрите бог знает какие видео. Вот отличный туториал, как подключится к mysql через jdbc https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-jdbc-tutorial/

Comment: Не знаю как в комьюнити, но в про версии есть отличные встроенные средства для подключения к базам данных (не только mysql). Бесплатную про версию можно легко найти на каких-нибудь торрентах. Но имейте ввиду, что это лишь утилита, которая упрощает работу с бд. Для разработки приложений она вам, фактически, ничем не поможет.

Comment: благодарю за туториал